# favicon works only on homepage but not on other pages

Tags: favicon

I have uploaded favicon.png to my Wordress 3.9.1 website: www.belldex.com and it works well.  I have already placed the favicon in other folders such as the theme's folder.

However, it only works on the homepage and not on any other page.

Appreciate being pointed to the right direction.

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser history and cache?

Comment: You only need to place the favicon in the root folder. Is your homepage on a different domain/sub-domain than your other pages?

Comment: I don't see the icon on the home page, even, on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using something like this inside your head tag 
AND If Homepage is on a different Domain/Subdomain than other pages: you will need to repeat

PS: .PNG is not as ideal as .ico, so I'd convert your image first, an in the case above, save in on the same level as your html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your `head` tag contains two links to favicons, and the second one doesn't work:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.belldex.com/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.belldex.com/wp-content/themes/smartit/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

You should delete the second one.

Comment: I think that must have been it.  I deleted manual entries of the favicon and uploaded it through themes API and all seems fine.  Thanks.